# Use Array.prototype.with in react-native project

Tags: typescript, react-native, babeljs, microsoft-metro, ecmascript-next

I'd like to use *Ecmascript 2023* array methods like `Array.prototype.with` in a react-native project. Are these supported at all, and if so, how can I enable the transformation of those?
I am on the latest `react-native@0.72` `typescript@5.2` and `node@21` (which both ts and node should support it). I guess it is a babel or metro issue, did any of you find a way to use this?

Comment: Can you share your `tsconfig.json`